# Probability of tie in chess match

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I'm a probability noob so i'm having trouble in a basic probability problem. I have the answer to it but i wanted some clarifications on how to solve it.
The problem is:

```
Two chess players, A and B, played 12 matches. A won 6, B won 4 and 2 were tied.
A and B decide to play three more matches. What is the probability of:

a) A winning all matches?
b) Two matches end up in tie

Answers: a)1/8; b)5/72
```

I could not solve this because i thought that to get the sample space i would have to calculate $3*3*3$ since there are three outcomes for each player in each match (victory, defeat, tie). If this was the case then the answer to a) would be $(1/3)  (1/3)  (1/3) = 1/27$. However, since the answer to a) is $1/8$ it seems to me that one should only consider two possible outcomes (victory or defeat) for A on each match. If only two outcomes are considered then indeed the answer is $(1/2)  (1/2) (1/2) = 1/8$. However i can`t wrap my head around as to why the ties are not counted.

As to b), obviously i could not solve this because i was still stuck on how i should handle the ties.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: the question doesnt seem to be well defined. At least what are the probabilities of three actions at each match?

Comment: This was the only information that was given to me. I guess one should assume all probabilities equal.

Comment: If that was the case, I would think the answer to a. would be 1/27, too.

Comment: Also, the answer for b. won't fit equal probability for each, unless I made a mistake doing the computations.

Comment: Oh man, that is so embarassing. There was a bit missing. I edited the question to add the missing part. I'm very sorry.

Comment: As I see it, the probabilities are to be calculated from previous match results, so P(A wins)=1/2, P(B wins)=1/3 and P(tied)=1/6, which fits the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're supposed to assume (perhaps rather strange assumption) that the results of the previous matches can be used to state the probability of outcomes of future matches.  So in any given match, $A$ wins with probability $\frac{6}{12}=\frac12$; $B$ wins with probability $\frac13$; and the match ends in a tie with probability $\frac16$.

I believe that these probabilities will be consistent with the answers you stated.

Answer (score 0):

you will use the given numbers as probabilities and the result for $a)$ is obvious since $P(A)=1/2$ and it is repeated independently for $3$ times and you get $(1/2)^3=1/8$

Part $b)$ is also simple you have binomial distribution with success probability of $1/6$ then you simply have $\binom{3}{2}(1/6)^2(5/6)=5/72$.